# Whether the disconnected state caused by session timeout is to be manually or automatically resolved?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#SessionTimeoutPerios

Once the session timeout has expired, and it goes into a disconnected state, when next does it try to re-establish a connection and whether this is automatic or manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Once the session timeout has expired, and it goes into a disconnected state, when next does it try to re-establish a connection and whether this is automatic or manual?

It's automatic and it happens based on an internal timer which checks certain internal tasks very often.

Comment: Any reference docs please?

Comment: Internals like this are not documented.